# Rails: Regex to exclude input after a character in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a rails app where in a certain field of a "new" view, the user can input some string that always looks something like this:

```
1303031110012015¿999999999999999
```

(Because it is the number of a membership card captured via a magnetic card reader)

What I want to do is to have a validation in the model with a regex for that field which lets me capture only the digits before the "¿" without it, something like:

**(In the model):**

```
validates_format_of :card_id, :with => /regex/i
```

and no matter if the user inputs the whole thing (because the machine always does), I want to save in the database only:

```
1303031110012015
```

How can that be achieved? Which is the correct Regex to use?

Comment: How the heck does `¿` show up in there? That you're getting non 7-bit ASCII in your data stream is perplexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validations check that data is valid, they don't clean things up. You want a `before_validation` callback to clean things up before they're validated. Something like this:

```
before_validation :clean_up_card_id, :if => :card_id_changed?

#...

private

def clean_up_card_id
    self.card_id = self.card_id.to_s.scan(/^\d+/)[0]
end
```

Then, because you're properly paranoid and know that everyone really is out to get out, validate it as well:

```
validates :card_id, :format => { :with => /\A\d+\z/, :msg => 'It done broke!' }
```

And if you know how long it should be, validate that too (either with `:length` or by replacing the `+` in the regex with the appropriate `{m,n}` limits).

Comment: That did it, Thanks! Very polished logic... BTW, ¿Any good tutorial you can recommend me about "Regexes" in Ruby? :)

Comment: @Jmlevick: I've been using regexes so long that I can't think of any tutorials, the [`Regexp` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html) tells you what features are available and what syntax is supported but that's the best I can do off the top of my head. One addition to the answer is that you should make `clean_up_card_id` private since (a) it is for internal use only and (b) there's no reason for it to be part of the model's public interface.